# Printing the last field of a column AWK

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following input:

```
10 0,12
10 1,14
10 2,63
20 0,12
20 1,98
20 3,15
```

I have three values associated to 10 and three for 20, so I would like to print the last value of each one of them (10 - 2,63 / 20 - 3,15) also including the 10 and 20 respectively. I have been trying but I couldn't make it.

I appreciate any hints you could provide me to fix this.

Regards.

Comment: Are they ordered? I mean, if you see one line starting with `10`, can there be others after lines with `20`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just compare the current 1st field with the previous one. If they do not match, print the previous line:

```
$ awk 'prev && id!=$1 {print prev} {prev=$0; id=$1} END {print prev}' a
10 2,63
20 3,15
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have always `10 x 10 x 10 x 20 x 20 x 20 x` ?

If you always have this schema, you can split your informations by spaces like :

```
echo "10 0,12 10 1,14 10 2,63 20 0,12 20 1,98 20 3,15" | awk '{split($0,n," "); print n[5],n[6],n[11],n[12]}'
```

What is inside this array ?

```
n[1] = 10
n[2] = 0,12
n[3] = 10
n[4] = 1,14
n[5] = 10
n[6] = 2,63
n[7] = 20
n[8] = 0,12
n[9] = 20
n[10] = 1,98
n[11] = 20
n[12] = 3,15
```

Answer (score 0):

This Awk should do it:

```
$ cat file
10 0,12 10 1,14 10 2,63 20 0,12 20 1,98 20 3,15
$ awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) a[$i]=$(i+1); for(k in a) print k, a[k]}' file
10 2,63
20 3,15
```

or if the file is in a different format:

```
$ cat file
10 0,12
10 1,14
10 2,63
20 0,12
20 1,98
20 3,15
$ awk '{a[$1]=$2}END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
10 2,63
20 3,15
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the support. The script is working now. I have used Fedorqui's method and is running ok.